# Sum of squares of digits of an integer in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive implementation of a method that takes a non-negative argument, and returns the sum of the squares of its digits. For example, sumSquareDigits(10) should return 1 and sumSquareDigits(103) should return 10.

This is my code :

```
public static int sumSquareDigits(int n) {
    if (n < 10) return n^2;
    return (((n % 10)^2) + sumSquareDigits(n/10));
    }
```

For example for an given integer 625, it would be something like:

(625 % 10)^2 + (62,5 % 10)^2 + (6,25)^2 = 5^2 + 2^2 + (6,25)^2

which of course is wrong because the last term should be 6 and not 6,25. What I am looking for is a way to truncate 6,25 so that it becomes 6.

How do we do this? And I'd appreciate any hints to implement this function better (I'm new in Java).

Thanks!

Comment: `n/10` will automatically truncate to an integer since `n` and `10` are both `int`s.  So that part of your code is already correct.  If you wanted a non-integer (for some other program), you'd need to write `n/10.0` or `n/10d` or `(double)n/10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, `^` is not "to the power" of, it is the bitwise XOR operator. To perform powers in Java use `Math.pow`. Bear in mind that `Math.pow` returns a double so you will need to cast it to an `int` if you only want a whole number. E.g.

```
if (n < 10) return (int)Math.pow(n, 2);
```

Of course, as msandiford pointed out, if you only need to calculate powers of 2, it is probably easier to just multiply a number by itself. E.g.

```
if (n < 10) return n * n;
```

Comment: When integer arguments and results are required, `x` squared is probably better expressed as `x * x` rather than complicating things with `Math.pow(...)`.

Comment: -_- I do not know why I didn't think of that - it's much simpler. Question updated; thanks.

Comment: @msandiford `x` squared is probably better expressed as `x * x` even if `x` is a floating-point number.  Using `pow` may require the machine to start taking logarithms of everything, which is more expensive, unless it optimizes for integer powers--I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

The `^` is for the bitwise XOR operator. You could use `Math.pow`, and cast the results to `int` since `Math.pow` returns a `double`:

```
public static int sumSquareDigits(int n) {
    if (n < 10) return (int) Math.pow(n, 2);
    return (int)((Math.pow((n % 10), 2)) + sumSquareDigits(n/10));
}
```

Or since it's only squared, just multiply the base by itself:

```
public static int sumSquareDigits(int n) {
    if (n < 10) return n * n;
    return ((n % 10) * (n % 10)) + sumSquareDigits(n/10);
}
```